# Nginx shows very high io wait for no reason

Tags: nginx

I have a streaming site running HLS video streams through Nginx cache proxy servers as simple CDN. The caching proxy shows high IO wait near 50% and with maximum HDD read near 40 mb/s. And out bandwidth near 400 mb/s as max network speed although it is supposed to be 1gb/s. When users count bypass certain number the performance drops down dramatically for no reason. Any help?

Comment: Your storage is too slow. Get faster storage.

Comment: No it is very fast and my data served from nginx cache

Comment: Then you aren't having a problem!